# Trigger code in salesforce

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

**How to write a trigger code to make the field as required and Not Required for a Object ,is it possible in trigger code to make the field as not Required and Required field in salesforce,Please Anyone Guide Me for the Answer**

Required field means in page layout we are Describing the field as Read only or Required, that things i have to do in trigger code is it Possible?

**I have to write a trigger code in Master detail Relationship between the objects, then the field is Required for Particular object,i want to replace the empty value in the object using trigger code is it Possible?**

Is there any code of field.isrequired option is there or Not ?

**Change to read-only a custom field with a trigger and make as Required in same code in trigger.this is my Question**

can we make Read only and Required field for custom object through coding,Is it possible

**Master Detail Relationship between Account and Custom Object
Trigger Scenario:
When Parent Record is deleted,child Record should not be deleted 
 I Have tried:

```
trigger notdeleteaccountrelatedcontacts1 on account (before delete) {
set<Id> aid = new set<Id>();

      list<account> tl=[select id from account where id=:trigger.old];
      for(account gh:tl){
            aid.add(gh.Id);
        }

       List<MDRCHECKING__c> con = [SELECT Id,Account56__c FROM MDRCHECKING__c WHERE Account56__c IN :aid];
       for(MDRCHECKING__c a : con ){
            a.Account56__c = null;
            update a;
        }

        }
```

Error:

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the
>   affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex
>   trigger notdeleteaccountrelatedcontacts1 caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator:
>   notdeleteaccountrelatedcontacts1: execution of BeforeDelete caused by:
>   System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable:
>   MDRCHECKING__c.Account56__c: Trigger.notdeleteaccountrelatedcontacts1:
>   line 13, column 1

How to Rectify the Error

Comment: Two things - update your question don't add comments. Potential answers may not read them. More importantly add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only addressing your error here:

The error is telling you that once the MD relationship is populated it cannot be modified. This means the setting on the relationship field is to **not** allow reparenting.

Even if it did, the relationship **cannot** be null so when the parent is deleted you cannot prevent the deletion of the child record, you could only reparent it to another master if you have the relationship set to allow reparenting.

If you want to prevent the records from being deleted you will need to change to a **lookup** relationship.

I do not understand your other questions, but in general, you can make a field required in code if it is not required on the object, but you cannot make a field non-required in code if it is required on the object.

Comment: it is not possible for to prevent the deletion of Child Records in trigger in Md Relationship

Comment: @user36188 - Is that a question or a statement? Either way, no it is not possible as outlined in the answer